# Android SAML 2.0 implementation

Tags: android, saml-2.0

i need to implement SAML 2.0 in one of my android app through Web view.
Does Anyone have the sample code for this, as i haven't used it before.

Comment: SAML is not appropriate for mobile devices which is why there are no samples. Use OpenID Connect / OAuth.

Comment: Thanks for ur response. But i have no other option than using SAML. I read it somewhere that using web view in android app we can implement SAML.

Comment: @nzpcmad is correct - the "right" thing to do is use OAuth in your application. If that means deploying a SAML SP endpoint on your application's server layer, then converting the SAML assertion to OAuth, then so be it. You cannot deploy an "App" that can act as an SP (well, you *could*, but it would be terribly foolish to do so).

Answer (score 0):

SAML is browser based because the whole flow is based on redirection and this is not appropriate for a mobile application. Also it has complex cryptography requirements and mobile libraries may not be available.

If you have to use SAML, then install thinktecture's IdentityServer and use OIDC into that and SAML out.

Comment: Hi.. can we use Proxy  server for SAML 2.0 implementation in android.

Comment: First Request will be sent to IDP url. Then IDP will send the token to proxy server from where our SP can collect that token to authenticate. Is this possible by this way

Comment: No idea - what does the Proxy server do? It sounds like you are massively overcomplicating the whole thing.

Comment: So, there is no way to implement SAML in Android ?

Comment: There is but you have to have some kind of embedded browser and then redirect at the end to a server and then get the token somehow from there. This is complicated, and the fact that you can't find any examples bears that out.

Comment: As u mentioned, OAuth2 is preferable for android , So can we implement by this way : OAuth2 will be the base but SAML request/response will be send/received to/from the IPD .